# Ubuntu Openstack Image for ESXi Server

Tags: 12.04, server, vmware, juju, openstack

What i already have :-> VMware ESXi Server installation configured and running

What i am trying to accomplish :->  install Ubuntu 12.x Open stack images under esxi bear metal as vMs and bring up open stack Open stack compute , glance and Swift under different VMs.

What i am looking for : Path for Ubuntu + Open stack 64 bit bundled Images and some instructions.

Any help?

--amru

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy on bare metal you might want to look into MAAS (https://maas.ubuntu.com/). You can deploy MAAS on your ESXi server and commission as many VMs as you'll need (that's your base environment). After that, using Juju, you can then deploy OpenStack on top of MAAS (that's your openstack environment). And finally, on top of that you can use Juju yet again to deploy workloads.